# How JVM handles handles Thread scheduling?

Tags: multithreading, jvm

May I know JVM handles Thread scheduling? How JVM handles unused threads (i.e) Threads that are not in running state. Does too much of unused threads is burden to JVM?

Comment: The OS manages the threads just like any other program. I suggest you look at how your OS manages threads.

Answer (score 1):

This is rather an open-ended question but I'll give you a quick synopsis.

Java has always had the concept of threads in the language.  Sometimes these map to OS threads but, where an OS does not support them (like Windows 95), the JVM can implement its own threading layer called green threads.  Today you can ignore green threads so the lowest level scheduling of JVM threads is handled by the OS.

However, all Java threads have a priority associated with them which allows you to signal to the JVM and OS which threads you consider to be more important than others in the context of scheduling.  This is a property of the Thread class and is accessed with getPriority/setPriority.  There are rules about how this value can be changed according to the security policy and the maximum thread priority.  Changing thread priorities to implement specific application behaviour is not recommended due to the different way platforms implement thread scheduling.

Java and the JVM make no guarantees about when threads will be scheduled.  When there is competition for processing resources, threads with higher priority are generally executed in preference to threads with lower priority. Importantly, this is not a guarantee that the highest priority thread will always be running. Thread priorities should not be used (or relied on) to implement mutual exclusion.

Unused threads will be garbage collected just like any other objects.  Because Threads are heavyweight objects that take time to create and remove, an application that intends to use lots of short-lived threads will typically implement some sort of thread pooling.  Too many threads will place a burden on the JVM, more so than other objects, because of the link to the underlying OS threads.

For more detailed information on Java threads and concurrency, I recommend reading Brian Goetz's excellent book, "Java Concurrency in Practice".